# How do you specify a custom build step in Qt Creator that executes when make completes?

Tags: qt-creator

I like Qt Creator to notify me when a compile is finished, so I went to the Projects Pane > Build > Build Steps > Add Build Step. However, I find that this custom build step is only executed when `make` exits successfully. If I have any compile errors then my custom step isn't executed, and I'm not notified.

How do you add a custom build step that executes even if you have compile errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit old question but I think I can share my solution:

what I'd do is:

1. disable make step
2. add custom step with:

   - command: `usr/bin/make`
   - argument: `; yourNotifyingScript`
   - directory: `%{buildDir}`

Using <kbd>;</kbd> will cause `yourNotifyingScript` run no matter if make passed or failed.